# fractions data type -- when to reduce?

Tags: python, integer

Here is my Python implementation of a simple fractions class:

```python
class frac:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __add__(self, x):
        return frac(self.a*x.b + self.b*x.a, self.b*x.b)    

    def __mul__(self, x):
        return frac(self.a*x.a, self.b*x.b)   

    def __sub__(self, x):
        return frac(self.a*x.b - self.b*x.a, self.b*x.b) 

    def __div__(self, x):
        return frac(self.a*x.b, self.b*x.a) 

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s/%s"%(self.a,self.b)
```

It does addition OK:

```
x = frac(1,3)
y = frac(1,2)
print x+ y

>> 5/6
```

However, it can miss the mark:

```
x = frac(1,3)
y = frac(2,3)
print x+ y

>> 9/9
```

It seems if I run this library enough, the numerators and denominators will get very large.  When should I start simplifying and where should I put that code?

---

There seems to be a fractions class already in Python, it this was instructive to put together.

My original goal was to allow for square roots of integers as well, but I will ask this in a separate question.

Comment: You might consider [accepcting](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would probably put it right in your `__init__` method, which simplifies it every time a fraction is created (which includes after any operation).

I disagree with Jaime's answer that you should do the simplification as part of the operation, as you'll have to copy/paste that code for every new operation.

I’d write something like:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x % y
    return x

class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self, numer, denom):
        cancel_factor = gcd(numer, denom)
        self.numer = numer / cancel_factor
        self.denom = denom / cancel_factor
```

A few other comments:

- Per [PEP 8 on class names](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), I'm using `Fraction` instead of `frac`.

  Also from PEP 8, I would put spaces around your multiplication operators.
- New style classes should inherit from `object` (as I've done above).
- I think `numer` and `denom` are better attribute names than `a` and `b`.
- The convention is to use `other` as the variable name in a method that takes two inputs, rather than `x`. For example:

  ```
  def __add__(self, other):
      new_numer = self.numer * other.denom + self.denom * other.numer
      new_denom = self.denom * other.denom
      return Fraction(new_numer, new_denom)
  ```
- I disagree with your use of `__repr__`. As a rule of thumb, `__repr__` should be something you can `eval()` to get back to that object; `__str__` is the human-readable object. See [difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for more.

  Here's what I'd write:

  ```
  def __repr__(self):
      return "Fraction(%s, %s)" % (self.numer, self.denom)

  def __str__(self):
      return "%s / %s" % (self.numer, self.denom)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to produce correct results, you should simplify after each operation. Euclid's algorithm is very fast in finding the GCD, and very simple to code. If you have a function like:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

Then you could rewrite, e.g. you `__add__` method as:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    num = self.a * other.b + self.b * other.a
    den = self.b * other.b
    gcf = gcd(num, den)

    return frac(num // gcf, den // gcf)
```

Comment: This simplification is needed in each function (and maybe even outside) so it should be a function of its own.

Comment: Euclid's algorithm may be fast compared with a naive approach, but if code reduces after every addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, it will spend more time doing the reductions than it spends doing everything else combined.

Comment: If you want correctness, you have to keep fractions in lowest terms. That the implementation in the standard Python library does exactly the same as @alexwlchan proposes, [see here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l163), is a good indicator that this is the proper way of going about it.